# numpy array of 2 dimensions indexing and sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

i have a doubt. There is an efficient way to sum all neighbors of a numpy matrix without using several conditions?

This is an example:

```
array([[5, 4, 8, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 7, 4, 5, 8, 5, 4, 7, 1, 1],
       [5, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 1, 7, 3],
       [6, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6],
       [6, 3, 5, 7, 3, 8, 5, 4, 7, 8],
       [4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 4, 5],
       [2, 1, 7, 6, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1],
       [6, 8, 8, 2, 8, 8, 1, 1, 3, 4],
       [4, 8, 4, 6, 8, 4, 8, 5, 5, 4],
       [5, 2, 8, 3, 7, 5, 1, 5, 2, 6]])
```

When I run `m[0][-1]` it returns me 3 and not an error, so if I want to add 1 to all neighbors of a value I need to use a lot of conditions because I can't just use `m[0][-1]` because in this case and in the other cases of the corners it returns me just a " False neighbor"

Comment: what's your expected output? what have you tried? haw many neibours you want to sum?

Comment: I think you just have to add one condition, that the indexes should be positive.

Comment: @UlisesBussi I want to add +1 to all neighbors for a specif value. But the total number of neighbors are different. E.g. for the first value 5 the neighbors are 2;4 and 7.

Comment: then you have to be carefull in the limits (when i=0 or i=len(m) and j=0 or j=len(m[0]). this should be your only conditions. but then you could call make 2 fors to find all neighbours or just save the cases as a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to add 1 to each neighbour of a cell with a given value.

For the example, let's add 1 to each cell in the neighborhood of a 7:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
v = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]])
a + convolve2d(a==7, v, mode='same')
```

output:

```
array([[6, 5, 9, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 7, 5, 5, 8, 5, 5, 8, 3, 2],
       [6, 3, 7, 4, 5, 5, 7, 3, 8, 4],
       [6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6, 3, 6, 8],
       [6, 3, 7, 8, 5, 8, 5, 5, 7, 9],
       [4, 2, 9, 9, 7, 2, 5, 8, 6, 6],
       [2, 2, 8, 8, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1],
       [6, 9, 9, 3, 8, 8, 2, 2, 4, 4],
       [4, 8, 4, 7, 9, 5, 8, 5, 5, 4],
       [5, 2, 8, 4, 7, 6, 1, 5, 2, 6]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to add 1 for all numbers/matrix instead only near a single value?

Comment: can you provide an example in your question?

Comment: Sorry, solved ;) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good @mozway solution, one very efficient solution is to use the **Numba stencil decorator combined with a parallel execution**. Here is an example:

```py
import numba as nb

# parallel=True is only useful for quite-big arrays
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def kernel(v):
    cond = np.zeros((v.shape[0]+2, v.shape[1]+2), dtype=np.bool_)
    cond[1:-1, 1:-1] = v == 7
    res = nb.stencil(lambda c: c[-1,-1]+c[-1,0]+c[-1,1]+c[0,-1]+c[0,1]+c[1,-1]+c[1,0]+c[1,1])(cond)
    return v + res[1:-1, 1:-1]

kernel(m)
```

An even faster solution consist in working **in-place** (using `v += res` instead of the `return v + res`). Here are the performance results for a 2000x2000 integer array on my 6-core machine:

```
scipy.signal.convolve2d:  124 ms
Numba out-of-place:        20 ms
Numba in-place:            15 ms
```

Note that the first call to `kernel` is slower due to the compilation time.
I also got a similar speed-up for smaller arrays (200x200).